# Unable to use a variable in mysql Select

Tags: mysql, variables, select

```
$select = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type=$row->title; ORDER BY id desc" .
         " LIMIT $low, $PerPage";
$final = mysql_query($select) or die('Error!');
```

$row->title; is previously created and it have value like Type1, Type2 or something else. When I start that script the result is "Error!". Could you tell me why? I have tried many ways to reslove the problem but without any result. This is one of them:

```
$mytype=$row->title;
$select = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type=$mytype; ORDER BY id desc" .
         " LIMIT $low, $PerPage";
$final = mysql_query($select) or die('Error!');
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ; after the $row-title i.e.:

```
$select = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type='$row->title'  ORDER BY id desc" .          " LIMIT $low, $PerPage";
```

Comment: Added quotes. Thx dqhendricks almost forgot :)

Answer (score 0):

**You should echo out mysql_error()** - MySQL will tell you what went wrong!

The answers by dqhendricks and Cybernate are correct - you should enclose your strings in single quotes.

However - **you should also be escaping your text**, or you will get more errors eventually:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type='" . mysql_real_escape_string($row->title) . "' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $low, $PerPage";
```